# Lion Osx Crash all Applications sometimes when i launch iphone simulator

Tags: macos, osx-lion, xcode4.1

it happened for me  a lot but it's not happening every time .. 
some times when i launch iphone application from xCode 4.1 in lion osx it closes all application and can't reopen them again unless i restart the machine.. what the wrong 
is this happen to me alone?

Answer (score 0):

File a bug at http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and hopefully the issue can be triaged.

The more info you provide in a bug, the better chance there is to figure out the cause.